# Why get the error "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'range' " in this python code?

Tags: python, types, range

I got an error on this code while trying to find prime numbers of the user's input:

```
get_value = int(input("How many number do you want to enter? "))
for num in range(get_value):
    numbers = int(input(f"Please enter your {num + 1} number: "))
    if num % range(2, num) == 0:
        print(f"the number {num} is prime")
    else:
        print("None of your number is not prime")
```

and this is the error:
`unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'range'`

I tried to convert the 'num' into string but I this also gave en error

Comment: What is `num % range(2, num)` supposed to do? You are calculating modulo between an int and a range, which is not defined. You probably wanted to write a loop

Comment: Did you mean something like `if all(num % div == 0 for div in range(2, num)):`?

Comment: as per both of the above comments,  it looks like the code has confused `for loops` with `if statements`....

Comment: I want to claculate the numbers between 2 and the last number the user give.the range is for this

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Yes, what should I do?

Comment: Replace your `if` with the one suggested by @BRemmelzwaal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that I run your code and let `num` be `3`. I will eventually run into the expression:

```py
3 % range(2, 3)
```

Already, there is a problem. `3` is of the type 'int', whereas `range`, rather than being a function, is a sequence type.

> class range(start, stop, step=1)
>
> Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence type, as documented in Ranges and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

Also shown in the documentation are valid operations that can be used on these sequence types.

[image: The Sequence Type Operations in Python]

As you can see, this type does not support modulo. **Modulo only works on integer operands.**

Below is a correct rendition of your intentions.

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True

get_value = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
prime_numbers = []

for num in range(get_value):
    number = int(input(f"Please enter your {num + 1} number: "))
    if is_prime(number):
        prime_numbers.append(number)

if prime_numbers:
    print("Prime numbers:", prime_numbers)
else:
    print("None of your numbers are prime")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are checking that each number is not dividable by each number starting from 2 until num - 1. Therefore, you need to change this statement

```
if num % range(2, num) == 0:
```

Here is a code:
`is_prime = lambda num: all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num))`

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
result = "prime" if is_prime(num) else "not prime"
print(f"{num} is {result}.")
```

Here is a complete version of the code

```
def is_prime(num):
if num <= 1:
    return False
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
return True

get_value = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
prime_found = False

for num in range(get_value):
    number = int(input(f"Please enter your {num + 1} number: "))
    if is_prime(number):
        prime_found = True
        print(f"The number {number} is prime.")
    else:
        print(f"The number {number} is not prime.")

if not prime_found:
    print("None of your numbers is prime.")
```